# How setting rvm in capistrano for Sinatra project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rvm, capistrano

I need in capistrano specify rvm for deploy Sinatra project to remote server

I have following **deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'sudoku'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:user/name-project.git'

set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/name-project'
set :linked_dirs, %w{ log }

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

This is information about rvm on remote server

```
deploy@ubuntu-512mb-fra1-01:~$ rvm info

    ruby-2.3.1:


  homes:
gem:          "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
ruby:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"


      environment:
        PATH:         "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin:/home/deploy/.rvm/bin"
        GEM_HOME:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1"
        GEM_PATH:     "/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1:/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global"
        MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1"
        IRBRC:        "/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/.irbrc"
        RUBYOPT:      ""
        gemset:       ""
```

What me add in deploy.rb for setting RVM? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

They have a gem for this: https://github.com/capistrano/rvm

Follow the installation instructions and then configure capistrano accordingly:

```
# deploy.rb or stage file (staging.rb, production.rb or else)
set :rvm_type, :user                     # Defaults to: :auto 
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.0.0-p247'      # Defaults to: 'default'
set :rvm_custom_path, '~/.myveryownrvm'  # only needed if not detected
```

Comment: thank you. wich correct path need I paste to set :rvm_custom_path, '~/.myveryownrvm'?

Comment: As said, you only need that if you have changed the default rvm path. as pointed here: https://github.com/capistrano/rvm#rvm-path-selection-rvm_type. Read the docs on the gem's github page.

Comment: i 100 times learned docs. i use this gem. but display error on remote server. ```Cannot execute /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.1-p112/ruby: No such file or directory (2)
```  In capfile i added ```set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.1-p112'```

Comment: And you have this very same version installed to the user set in the configs?

Comment: on remote server ruby -v ```ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]```

Comment: How do you installed rvm in this machine? It's per user, system wide ?

Comment: ```sudo adduser deploy
sudo adduser deploy sudo
su deploy``` next  ```rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1 --default``` I think per user, becose if i change user to root, rvm command not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129551/discussion-between-stefan-hansch-and-lcguida).